# Convert floats array to raster

Tags: pyqgis, esri-ascii-raster

I have a numpy array that contains floats values.
Once converted to raster, the values are all integers.
How can i keep the float format?

The procedure I use is:

```
geotransform = [xmin, xsize, 0, ymax, 0, -ysize]
Raster = np.array(values_array)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outputRaster = 'output/path/to/raster.tif'
dst_ds = driver.Create(outputRaster, cols, rows,  1, gdal.GDT_Int16)
band = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.WriteArray( Raster )
band.SetNoDataValue(-9999)
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
epsg = MaskGrid.crs().postgisSrid()
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(epsg)
dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )
dst_ds = None
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The raster you are creating has an integer datatype as specified in your code: `dst_ds = driver.Create(outputRaster, cols, rows,  1, gdal.GDT_Int16)`. You need to change the last argument to one of the floating point data types. Here is the documentation on raster datatypes: http://gdal.org/1.11/gdal_8h.html#a22e22ce0a55036a96f652765793fb7a4

Comment: @JacobF, thanks, though it was trivial I did not think about it!